# How to bundle native macos executable with a flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to bundle a native console program for macos written in Rust, into a Flutter app.

The Flutter app needs to call this program from Dart with something like this:

```
Process.runSync("./myconsoleapp", ["argument1", "argument2"]);
```

The Flutter app can't seem to find `myconsoleapp`.

Is there a way to embed `myconsoleapp` into the Flutter app, and make it executable? I tried manually adding and it didn't work.

Steve

Comment: The fact that you mentioned the language the command line executable was written in suggests that you have the source code for it. Is there a reason you want to consume it as a separate process rather than building it as a library and calling into it with FFI?

Answer (score 2):

Flutter for windows simply bundle project.exe along with a bunch of other files into a directory in (`build\windows\runner\debug\`). No one can stops you from adding your files to that directory.

In your dart code, simply start a new process from the newly added file:

```dart
var exePath =
    p.join(p.dirname(Platform.resolvedExecutable), 'myFile.exe');
var result = await Process.run(exePath);
```

Answer (score 1):

It can't find your executable because there is no relationship between `./`--which is the current directory in the environment your app was launched from--and your application's location. If you want to access something bundled in your application you should be using `NSBundle`'s `pathForResource:ofType:` to get the path to it (either via a method channel, or FFI).

> Is there a way to embed myconsoleapp into the Flutter app,

You would add it as a bundled resource via Xcode. (There's nothing Flutter-specific about this step.)

> and make it executable?

Presumably the product of your Rust build process is already executable.